# MySQL does not use index in table join

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I have 2 table, product and product_pic with 100K rows.

I have index on porduct_id on product_pic table but mysql dose not use index on joining them!

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `keyword` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `summary` text COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `note` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `catid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `expdate` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `show` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `hit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `usertype` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `rand` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `provinceid` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `expdate_email` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `active_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `weight` float NOT NULL,
  `ucategory` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
  `searchstatus` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `vitreen` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `summery` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `notification` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `active_buy` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `autotranslate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `usertype` (`usertype`),
  KEY `catid` (`catid`),
  KEY `active` (`active`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `update_time` (`update_time`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `note` (`note`,`keyword`,`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42987 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

product pic:

```
 CREATE TABLE `product_pic` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `productid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `pic` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `default_img` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`,`productid`),
  KEY `productid` (`productid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48020 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

I try to use hint but nothing happend!

our query:

```
SELECT p.`id`, p.`title` name, product_pic.`pic` 
FROM `product` p
LEFT JOIN `product_pic` USE INDEX (productid)  ON p.`id`=product_pic.`productid`
where p.id in (SELECT * FROM `PID`) GROUP BY p.`id`;
```

Explain output:

```
+------+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                           |
+------+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | p           | ALL    | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |    1 | Using temporary; Using filesort                 |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | product_pic | ALL    | productid     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |    1 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | PID         | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | p.id |    1 | Using index                                     |
+------+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

our query take 3 min for 36 row !!

```
36 rows in set (3 min 27.481 sec)
```

Comment: Questions about performance or indexes should include table structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLE table`) for every table involved in the query.. Also we need to see the query and explain (`EXPLAIN query`).. Without that information the question is unclear and most likely will be voteclosed.

Comment: and the query that's not working?  Please edit post and show, don't add via comment

Comment: @RaymondNijland is it ok now?

Comment: @DRapp yes it work but take too time!

Comment: create structure off the PID table is still missing? .. but you better off into also reading [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected result as your GROUP BY is [invalid](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dqzdvXmMaPKjsKNiuYuMT9/0) by SQL standards, and should not even be used.

Comment: Explain tells you that only 1 row was found and looked at, you can invoke all kinds of rituals and black magic but it doesn't get any better than that. Your query is slow because of `SELECT * FROM PID` since it gets a ton of data which you then group, not because MySQL isn't using an index (which it doesn't need). An index is used to **reduce** number of rows inspected. `SELECT * from X` -> no index can be used here, it reads the whole table. Index is not a magic potion you throw at query which makes it faster...

Answer (score 1):

- Is there at most 1 pic per product?  If so, you don't need the `GROUP BY`.
- If there are multiple pics per product, then the `GROUP BY` is improperly used -- after the `GROUP BY`, which product_pic.`pic`  do you want it to show?
- `where p.id in (SELECT * FROM PID)` --> `JOIN PID USING(id)`
- The `EXPLAIN` uses bogus -- it says `ALL`, but `Rows=1`, Is there only one row in each table??
- Independent of other changes, change `KEY (productid)` to `KEY(productid, pic)`.
- Avoid index hints.

Comment: * no there are multiple pic but when I remove GROUP BY the problem exist * no there are more than one row in each table * I test it in mariadb but I think it's OK in mysql (explain show that it's correct but I don't check the performance) * I will test the changing the key * thanks